# How to pause wget download that was running by PHP's shell_exec()?

Tags: php, linux, exec, wget, shell-exec

I use the following code to download a file from a remote server using wget

```
shell_exec("wget -O {FILENAME} {FILE_URL}");
```

if I was using the terminal I could pause the download by hitting ctrl+c

how can I pause wget in php?

Comment: `Ctrl+C` isn't a pause, its canceling.

Comment: in wget you can resume downloading the file after ctrl+c after adding -c to the same command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to get `ID` of the process. You can do that by running

```
ps -uax | grep wget | awk '{print $2}'
```

After that you can get a list of PID of processes that match to grep request.

Then use `kill` command to send your signal to process.  Here is some signals descriptions used by `kill`, you can [read more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317492/list-of-kill-signals) regarding unix signals.

```
  1       HUP (hang up)
  2       INT (interrupt)
  3       QUIT (quit)
  6       ABRT (abort)
  9       KILL (non-catchable, non-ignorable kill)
  14      ALRM (alarm clock)
  15      TERM (software termination signal)
```